# Does anyone know what this photodiode circuit is for?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, photodiode

I'm looking at some circuits for some sensitive photodiodes and I'm a little confused about what the following is doing. For context, this is connected between the output of the first stage TI and the non-inverting input to the second stage amplifier.

[image: The circuit in question]

I assume this is a type of filter but it's not one I've seen before and was wondering if anyone could give me some more information?

Comment: yep. So, consider C1 and R1 in parallel as one complex impedance, and see how it forms a voltage divider with R2. Then, apply the same "solve for V1 in dependence of f" that you learned when you learned about the Bode diagrams of CR and RC filters.

Comment: (hint hint: schematics get better when you add designators to components, and name the relevant nodes. Otherwise, the first commenter gets to do that…)

Comment: Please show the fuller circuit. What it is for depends entirely on what it does and the circuit details are needed for that.

Comment: Basically, it's an edge detector.